# J: Handy method to enter a matrix?

Tags: matrix, j

I have a *n*-by-*m* matrix written at paper and I want to make calculations on it in J.
I can enter matrices like that (*n* = 3, *m* = 3):

```
   A =: 3 4 $ 1 3 2 4 7 8 1 2 2 0 0 1
```

The question is how to enter a matrix like that:

```
   A =: (something here)
1 3 2 4
7 8 1 2
2 0 0 1
)
```

The reason why I'm asking such a weird question is that I have seen in some book a similar method of typing matrices using verb `0 : 0` or something alike, but I cannot remember where. **:{**

Comment: It's much easier to remember `noun define` than `0 : 0`, and I find code clearer and more maintainable with `verb define` than `3 : 0` or `adverb def 'blah blah blah'` than `1 : 'blah blah blah'` etc.

Comment: yes, good remark, although I like `0 :0` more :). I've read once `0 :0` and `3 :0`, remembered and since that time I forgot about `verb define` and others. that's a matter of taste :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `(something here)` as `(".;._2) 0 : 0`. That way I can also mix expressions.

```
] A =: (".;._2) 0 : 0
5 $ 0
? 5 $ 5
5 $ 1
1 2 3 2 1
)
0 0 0 0 0
2 1 0 0 3
1 1 1 1 1
1 2 3 2 1
```

Comment: Thank you. @Tikkanz 's answer is more detailed, but yours looks laconic - in J style, so to say. :) And ability to mix expressions is really awesome!

Answer (score 2):

The use of dyadic (rather than monadic) `".` will attempt to resolve each line as a string of numbers rather than evaluate it as a J sentence. Where a string cannot be resolved to a number, the left argument (`_99` in the example below) is used instead. This approach will correctly interpret a larger set of numbers represented as strings.

The choice of `noun define` rather than `0 : 0` simply saves a set of brackets that is otherwise needed to separate the `_2` from the `0`.

```
   ]A =: _99&".;._2 noun define
1 -3 2 4
7 8 1 2
2 0 0 1
)
1 _3 2 4
7  8 1 2
2  0 0 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I agree about `noun define`, although I believe that every J programmer firstly learns what conjunction `:` is together with `0 :0`, so he knows what is `0 :0`. And what I like in this form is that it looks like egg `0` falling at someone's screaming face `:0`. ahah :D