# J Language: Reading large 2D matrix

Tags: matrix, io, j

I'm a J newbie, and am trying to import one of my large datasets for further experimentation. It is a 2D matrix of doubles, approximately 80000x50000. So far, I have found two different methods to load data into J.

The first is to convert the data into J format (replacing negatives with underscores, putting exponential notation numbers into J format, etc) and then load with (adapted from [J: Handy method to enter a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241527/j-handy-method-to-enter-a-matrix)):

```
(".;._2) fread 'path/to/file'
```

The second method is to use `tables/dsv`.

I am experiencing the same problem with both methods: namely, that these methods work with small matrices, but fail at approximately 10M values. It seems the input just gets truncated to some arbitrary limit. How can I load matrices of arbitrary size? If I have to convert to some binary format, that's OK, as long as there is a description of the format somewhere.

I should add that this is a 64-bit system and build of J, and I can successfully create a matrix of random numbers of the appropriate size, so it doesn't seem to be a limitation on matrix size per se but only during I/O.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I did not find what exactly was causing this, but thanks to Dane, I did find a workaround by using JMF ( 'data/jmf' package). It turns out that JMF is just straight binary data with no header and native (?) or little-endian data can be mapped directly with `JFL map_jmf_ 'x';'whatever.bin'`

Comment: Are you running out of memory? Can you give a line of J that produces dummy data that matches the precision and general shape of what you're generating?

Comment: I think what you may be seeing is normal truncation of *display in the REPL*. Try, for example, `i.1e3 1e3` and you'll notice that you won't see all million entries - only the top (or bottom) part of the table.  If you do `$ (".;._2) fread 'path/to/file'`, does it have the size/shape you expect?

Comment: I'm glad JMF solves your problem. I've been looking into this more and I don't think your phrase was doing what you intended. `fread` should just be reading your file into a string, just as `1!:1` does. `(".;._2)` uses the last byte of your string as the delimiter, cuts up your string **dropping every instance of your delimiter**, and converts each portion into a number, if possible. Try on `(".;._2) '1e3 5 2.345e9 '` for size. Note the final space in the string.

Comment: I'm super curious now. Can you share the first few megabytes of your file? I'd like to work out my own way to import it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay -- here it is: http://corygil.es/data/stackoverflow/GPL13534.sample.xz . Good luck ;)

Comment: Oh, and this file has a  header and index column I didn't remove; you can generate the actual input with ``unxz $file | cut -f2- | sed 1d``. Unfortunately, I can't remember the actual file I was using for testing (I have 1000s of similar files), but this one is perfectly representative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running out of memory. A quick test to see how much space integers take up yields the following:

```
   7!:2 'i. 80000 5000'
8589936256
```

That is, an 80,000 by 5,000 matrix of integers requires 8 GB of memory. Your 80,000 by 50,000 matrix, if it were of integers, would require approximately 80 GB of memory.

Your next question should be about performing array or matrix operations on a matrix too big to load into memory.

Comment: I just noticed that you said you created an 80,000 by 50,000 array of random numbers successfully. What's the line of J you used for that?

Comment: I did ``m =: ?. 80000 50000 $ 4000000000`` successfully and once it finished could do basic operations on ``m``. I have 128GB of RAM (and more is on the way), but my problems with the I/O start with a much smaller input matrix, on the order of 10000x10000.

Comment: And yes, I'd very much like to use J's mmap facilities, even for matrices that will fit into memory, but my problem there is converting the data to that format. I cannot find anywhere that JMF format is described in such a way that I can write something to convert my TSV to it. Is it simply just the raw binary (numeric) data? What endianness? (sorry if OT)